# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm facing this error when trying to start the application.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Testen {   
    public static void main( String[] args){ 
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I've already read threads of people who were facing similar errors, however, I'm failing to apply their solutions to my code.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to start the application without providing any command line arguments. I'd expect to run it as something like `java Testen 10`

Answer (score 0):

As someone is the comments pointed out, when you run java code from command line like this: `java testen arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3`, then these arguments are stored inside the the string array `String[] args`. To access the `arg0` you can use `args[0]` in your code.

If you run `java testen` then your string array `args` will be empty, so you can't access an element that doesn't exist, and you get the exception.